# account has status picklist values ->In Progress , Approved. It should only be approved when all of its related contact status becomes Approved

Tags: validation-rule

```
AND(
    ISPICKVAL(Status__c, "Approved"),
    NOT(ISBLANK(Contact)),
    NOT(INCLUDES(Contact.Status__c, "In Progress"))
)
```

I'm getting error

> Error: Field Contact does not exist. Check spelling.

Answer (score 1):

your problems comes from the fact that you are not taking your object hierarchy the right way.

What i mean is that one account has many contacts. As you are on the parent side of the relationship you cannot say `contact.status` as they may be many contacts.
The dot notation is when you are on the child side of the relation and that you are going upwards to the parent. Indeed a contact has only ONE parent account thus you can say `yourContact.Account.Name` while the other way around would return many contact (`yourAccount.contacts`) and then for each of the contact you need to perform the check.

In order to make a validation for this usecase you need to create a flow that does the check or make an Apex validation that has an `addError()` in the before trigger context.